# how to check radio button based on function return value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have radio buttons in a table and I am calling a function on onchange event of it.

```
@if(some condiotion)
{
    <td><input type="radio"  onChange="launch('@data.getVersion()')"name="isDefault" value="default" checked="checked"></td>
}
else
{
    <td><input type="radio"  onChange="launch('@data.getVersion')" name="isDefault" value="default" ></td>
}
```

My launch function can fail in certain conditions. In that case I dont want my radio button to get checked.

How can I achieve this? tried some ways but could not do this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show you complete code what you have to tried?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("[name='isDefault']").click(function(){
   if(this.checked){
     $("[name='isDefault']").prop("checked", false);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name='isDefault']").click(function(){

   if(this.checked){
        $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
   }
});
```

try this Code
I think it will work

Comment: this syntax is wrong. Correct is $(this).attr('checked', 'checked') attr don't allow true false type boolean value. for boolean you can use .prop()